# Lost internet connection of the app when write some code in terminal for another app

Tags: swift, xcode

I write some code and install gem, cocoa pod and ruby on terminal for another app location file but seems like these installations installed on Xcode : my commands on terminal that run was this :

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm install ruby-[version]

export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
gem install cocoapods --user-install
```

Dear guys ,
Actually I want to return on first state before I install these line because my another Xcode project that is really important , not working , how could I do to solve this problem?
for your attention thanks alot.

following line is some error that i facing with in debug area :

```
   2021-08-30 13:41:48.774954+0430 offerNews[3999:146045]   Connection 1: received failure notification
2021-08-30 13:41:48.775252+0430 offerNews[3999:146045] Connection  1: failed to connect 12:8, reason -1
2021-08-30 13:41:48.775473+0430 offerNews[3999:146045] Connection 1: encountered error(12:8)
 2021-08-30 13:41:48.822838+0430 offerNews[3999:146037] Task <D97DE843-5D1D-4970-B7FA-D11F64800BE3>.<0> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [12:8])
2021-08-30 13:41:48.823608+0430 offerNews[3999:146037] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1003
2021-08-30 13:41:48.865862+0430 offerNews[3999:145966] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028efa70 UIView:0x7fe90cf28e60.height == 50   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028e38e0 V:|-(10)-[UIStackView:0x7fe90cf28cd0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe90cf28b60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d0050 V:[UIStackView:0x7fe90cf28cd0]-(10)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe90cf28b60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d0550 UIStackView:0x7fe90cc19a60.top == UILayoutGuide:0x6000032f7560'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d0780 UILayoutGuide:0x6000032f7560'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom == UIStackView:0x7fe90cc19a60.bottom   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d1b30 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fe90cf28cd0.top == UIView:0x7fe90cf28e60.top   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d1b80 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIStackView:0x7fe90cf08340]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fe90cf28cd0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d1f90 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fe90cc19a60.top == UIView:0x7fe90cc19ff0.top   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d1fe0 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIView:0x7fe90cf29150]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fe90cc19a60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d1c20 'UISV-fill-equally' UIStackView:0x7fe90cf08340.height == UIView:0x7fe90cf28e60.height   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d2080 'UISV-fill-equally' UIView:0x7fe90cf28b60.height == UIView:0x7fe90cc19ff0.height   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d2120 'UISV-fill-equally' UIView:0x7fe90cf29150.height == UIView:0x7fe90cc19ff0.height   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d1bd0 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIView:0x7fe90cf28e60]-(15)-[UIStackView:0x7fe90cf08340]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d2030 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIView:0x7fe90cc19ff0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fe90cf28b60]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d20d0 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIView:0x7fe90cf28b60]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fe90cf29150]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d23a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fe90cc198f0.height == 667   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d0640 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-bottom' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000032f7560'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe90cc198f0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028d05a0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-top' V:|-(20)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000032f7560'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe90cc198f0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028efa70 UIView:0x7fe90cf28e60.height == 50   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-08-30 13:41:53.100353+0430 offerNews[3999:146037] Connection 2: received failure notification
2021-08-30 13:41:53.100586+0430 offerNews[3999:146037] Connection 2: failed to connect 12:8, reason -1
2021-08-30 13:41:53.100962+0430 offerNews[3999:146037] Connection 2: encountered error(12:8)
2021-08-30 13:41:53.106221+0430 offerNews[3999:146045] Task <74E4D6A1-E3AC-4CF0-B3C1-5DA6424C9DDA>.<0> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [12:8])
2021-08-30 13:41:53.106746+0430 offerNews[3999:146045] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1003
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “citys” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=https://api.offernews.co/api/citys}
2021-08-30 13:41:53.121206+0430 offerNews[3999:146045] Connection 3: received failure notification
2021-08-30 13:41:53.121414+0430 offerNews[3999:146045] Connection 3: failed to connect 12:8, reason -1
2021-08-30 13:41:53.121819+0430 offerNews[3999:146045] Connection 3: encountered error(12:8)
2021-08-30 13:41:53.126050+0430 offerNews[3999:146037] Task <066F3763-D89D-4B24-9767-CFC7AA1DE87A>.<0> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [12:8])
2021-08-30 13:41:53.126349+0430 offerNews[3999:146037] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1003
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “citys” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=https://api.offernews.co/api/citys}

2021-08-30 13:41:55.916065+0430 offerNews[3999:146045] Connection 4: received failure notification
2021-08-30 13:41:55.916257+0430 offerNews[3999:146045] Connection 4: failed to connect 12:8, reason -1
2021-08-30 13:41:55.916600+0430 offerNews[3999:146045] Connection 4: encountered error(12:8)
2021-08-30 13:41:55.922064+0430 offerNews[3999:146042] Task <B3949210-9E23-42CF-9935-5AA704844E30>.<0> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [12:8])
2021-08-30 13:41:55.922544+0430 offerNews[3999:146045] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1003
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “citys” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=https://api.offernews.co/api/citys}
2021-08-30 13:41:55.929545+0430 offerNews[3999:146042] Connection 5: received failure notification
2021-08-30 13:41:55.929733+0430 offerNews[3999:146042] Connection 5: failed to connect 12:8, reason -1
2021-08-30 13:41:55.930229+0430 offerNews[3999:146042] Connection 5: encountered error(12:8)
2021-08-30 13:41:55.934136+0430 offerNews[3999:146037] Task <3150191D-0192-4A7E-9643-5F5D4342159D>.<0> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [12:8])
2021-08-30 13:41:55.934535+0430 offerNews[3999:146037]  NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1003
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “citys” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=https://api.offernews.co/api/citys}
```

Comment: What are the errors you are facing with new updates?

Comment: @AbdulHoqueNuri i add every thing in my debug console area

Comment: I think, there is no relation to your updates, Check your UI constraints, Your API is not working and Try to clean your Xcode derived data and reinstall app again. I will check, If I found something related to your issue.